# 「大きい方」と「一番大きい」と「最大」の違いはなんですか？

Tags: words

These are 3 words I've learned from experience rather than a textbook, and although I hear them in different contexts as far as I can tell they all mean the same thing. Could someone clarify what the difference is between 大きい方, 一番大きい, and 最大? Is it formality? Are they all the same?

Comment: I can't really comment on the difference of 一番大きい and 最大.  But, 大きい方 means "bigger" not "biggest".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented, 大きい方 is *the bigger/larger* and the other two are superlatives, meaning something is the largest/biggest according to some measure.

大きい方 can mean *the bigger (of the two)* or *bigger than average*.

- 大きい方のりんご - the bigger apple of the two
- 彼はクラスでは大きい方だ - He is taller than average in his class.

一番大きい and 最大 basically mean the same, but they are not always interchangeable. 最大 is like *maximum/max* in English.

- 彼はクラスで一番大きい - He is the tallest in his class.

Here 最大 can't be used. And also

- 最大のりんご

is not really idiomatic; at best, it sounds like the particular kind of apple that is the largest. Or more commonly, 最大の哺乳類 (the largest mammal) denotes whales.

Mostly it depends on collocations which of 一番大きい and 最大 is natural, but my feeling is that 最大 is used in more specialized contexts or for abstract things.